# how to generate api-key for postman in rest controller spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I have this `spring boot` build. I want to consume `rest controller` `@GetMapping` API.

I know the credentials. I can open its dashboard using login page.

But I am not able to consume `Rest apis` from postman due authorization setting.

Below is the `REST api` that I want to consume in `postman client`

```java
      @GetMapping("/students")
        @ApiOperation(value = "", authorizations = {@Authorization(value = "apiKey")})
        public Response getAllStudents() {
            return Response
                    .ok()
                    .setPayload(studentService.getStudents());
        }
```

As I mentioned I know the username/password. How can I generate this `apiKey` field and configure in my `postman` window.

Answer (score 0):

In postman go to Authorization > API key. enter your credentials and it should work

Comment: When I do AddTo -> Header it says `Error: Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["MyUserName"]`

Comment: When I do AddTo -> QueryParams it adds my username in params field key and my password in params field value. I think I have to generate some key string out this credential combination ..

Comment: In key I am giving my username and in value I am giving my password